# If I have a starting and an ending IP, how can I find the subnet?

Tags: python, routes, ip, subnet

I need to block some IPs from some countries but I'm only given the starting IP and the ending IP like this:

```
11.22.33.44 - 11.22.35.200
```

I'd like to calculate the subnet to have it like this:

```
(not accurate)

11.22.33.44/14
```

How can I determine the subnet given an IP address range in Python?

Comment: I was going to vote to close this as an off-topic networking question, but I see that you've included the Python tag. Are you trying to do this _in Python code_?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do it in python, but I am comfortable with a pseudo code too

Comment: how about using the built-in [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.subnets) module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't spent much time networking recently, but here's how I think you can do this most efficiently.

First of all, it's important to recognize that not all IP ranges can be represented as a single subnet. Let's take a look at a common subnet like

```
192.168.0.0/24
```

The `/24` indicates that the first 24 bits of `192.168.0.0` give the network prefix, in this case `192.168.0` and the remaining bits are used for host addressing. You get a range from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.0.255`.

[`ipcalc`](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) can help us out here. Let's see if it agrees:

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255
deaggregate 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255
192.168.0.0/24
```

So far so good. But what if you want to exclude the `.0` or the `.255`, which is used for broadcast? There isn't a single subnet that represents that range:

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.254
deaggregate 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.254
192.168.0.0/25
192.168.0.128/26
192.168.0.192/27
192.168.0.224/28
192.168.0.240/29
192.168.0.248/30
192.168.0.252/31
192.168.0.254/32
```

Subnets grow by powers of two and when our range doesn't slot into that framework cleanly we end up with things like this.

The example you gave, incidentally, doesn't give a single subnet:

```
$ ipcalc 11.22.33.44 - 11.22.35.200
deaggregate 11.22.33.44 - 11.22.35.200
11.22.33.44/30
11.22.33.48/28
11.22.33.64/26
11.22.33.128/25
11.22.34.0/24
11.22.35.0/25
11.22.35.128/26
11.22.35.192/29
11.22.35.200/32
```

Python has an `ipaddress` module. Let's see if [its `summarize_address_range()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.summarize_address_range) agrees with `ipcalc` (formatted for readability):

```
>>> import ipaddress

>>> list(ipaddress.summarize_address_range(
        ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.0.0'),
        ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.0.255')))

[IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/24')]
```

So far so good. How about the second example?

```
>>> list(ipaddress.summarize_address_range(
        ipaddress.IPv4Address('11.22.33.44'),
        ipaddress.IPv4Address('11.22.35.200')))

[IPv4Network('11.22.33.44/30'),
 IPv4Network('11.22.33.48/28'),
 IPv4Network('11.22.33.64/26'),
 IPv4Network('11.22.33.128/25'),
 IPv4Network('11.22.34.0/24'),
 IPv4Network('11.22.35.0/25'),
 IPv4Network('11.22.35.128/26'),
 IPv4Network('11.22.35.192/29'),
 IPv4Network('11.22.35.200/32')]
```

Looks like a match to me.

Answer (score -2):

1. convert IP addresses to unsigned long: a.b.c.d = ((a*256+b)*256+c)*256+d
2. apply a binary exclusive OR to both addresses as unsigned long
3. count bits that are zero (equal in both addresses) from highest to lowest - that's your maximum shared prefix length

You example in binary for clarity:

```
11.22.33.44  = 00001011 00010110 00100001 00101100
11.22.35.200 = 00001011 00010110 00100011 11001000
XOR            00000000 00000000 00000010 11100100
```

That's 22 zero bits from the beginning, a /22 subnet.

The subnet mask for /22 is `255.255.252.0`. Apply that to any of the above addresses, that's the network address. Combined: **11.22.32.0/22**. That is the smallest subnet/longest prefix combining both start and end address.